# Close activity that was launch from a new intent

Tags: android, nfc

I am having problems with the app backstack, what i want to achieve is when button exit pressed, closed all activities, so when i open the app and after login checked, this activity is launched. If i pressed the exit button, all activities are closed, now if i read the tag, it launches the activity, the toast on create is fire, the toast on resume is fired, the toast `onread` intent is fired, and the rest goes well, and i can save the tag data into the server.
Now i try to close the app by clicking the exit button, and instead of closing all activities, it goes to the same activity, and then i pressed exit button again and the app is closed.
How can i close all activities after reading the tag.
**TagsActivty2.java:**

```
 public class TagsActivity2 extends Activity {
private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
private ImageView mScanner;
private Animation mAnimation;

String   user="",posto="",conn="",tagsvisitadassemnet="",serverselecionado="",urlpost="",content="1a";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);  
    user=gameSettings.getString("User", "");
     posto=gameSettings.getString("Posto", "");
     conn=gameSettings.getString("Conn", "");
     serverselecionado= gameSettings.getString("server", "");
     //Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "servidor selecionado:"+serverselecionado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "on create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    if(posto.equals("admin")==true)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tags2);
        else
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tags2_noadmin);    
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);

        //ver conecao a internet
      //qual das imagens carregar, rede on ou redeoff
        if(conn.equals("yes")==true)
        {


        //  Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "tem internet para descarregar dados...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.titlebarconn);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.rede);
              //verificar se existem dados gravados durante offline

                tagsvisitadassemnet=gameSettings.getString("tagsvisitadas", "");
                if(tagsvisitadassemnet.length()>0)
                {
          //            Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "existem dados offline:"+tagsvisitadassemnet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //carregar os dados e apagar

                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = gameSettings.edit();  
                prefEditor.putString("tagsvisitadas", ""); 


                prefEditor.commit();  

                }

        }
        else
        {
            //Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "sem internet",       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.titlebarconn); 
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.redeoff);

        }
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.titlebarTitleTxt)).setText(user);

    mScanner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

    mScanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TranslateAnimation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
             TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
             TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.2f,
             TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
             TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f);
    mAnimation.setDuration(3000);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    mScanner.setAnimation(mAnimation);



    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, NFC is not available on this device",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //finish();
    }




    Button bsair= (Button) findViewById(R.id.titlebarRefreshBtn);

       bsair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);  
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = gameSettings.edit();  
                prefEditor.putString("User", ""); 
                prefEditor.putString("UserName", "");
                prefEditor.putString("Password", "");
                prefEditor.putString("Posto", "");

                prefEditor.commit();  
              Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "sair", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setResult(2);
                finish();
            }
        });

       Button bultimoscheckins= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tagsvisitadas);

       bultimoscheckins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(TagsActivity2.this, Lastcheckins.class);

                  startActivityForResult(i, 2);
            }
        }); 

       Button breadtags= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_opcoes);

       breadtags.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(TagsActivity2.this,Opcoes.class);

                  startActivityForResult(i, 2);
            }
        });
       if(posto.equals("admin")==true)
       {
       Button bwritetags= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_escrevertags);

       bwritetags.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(TagsActivity2.this, WriteTags.class);

                  startActivityForResult(i, 2);
            }
        });
       }

}

private boolean isWriteReady = false;

/**
 * Enable this activity to write to a tag
 * 
 * @param isWriteReady
 */
public void setTagWriteReady(boolean isWriteReady) {
    this.isWriteReady = isWriteReady;
    if (isWriteReady) {
        IntentFilter[] writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) };
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(TagsActivity2.this, NfcUtils.getPendingIntent(TagsActivity2.this),
                writeTagFilters, null);
    } else {
        // Disable dispatch if not writing tags
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(TagsActivity2.this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // onResume gets called after this to handle the intent
     Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "on new intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
     Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "on resume", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (isWriteReady && NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        processWriteIntent(getIntent());
    } else if (!isWriteReady
            &&                             (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction()) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED
                    .equals(getIntent().getAction()))) {
        processReadIntent(getIntent());
    }
}

private static final String MIME_TYPE = "application/com.tapped.nfc.tag";

/**
 * Write to an NFC tag; reacting to an intent generated from foreground
 * dispatch requesting a write
 * 
 * @param intent
 */
public void processWriteIntent(Intent intent) { 
    if (isWriteReady &&    NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {

        Tag detectedTag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    //  String tagWriteMessage = mTextField.getText().toString();
        //byte[] payload = new String(tagWriteMessage).getBytes();

        //if (detectedTag != null && NfcUtils.writeTag(
        //      NfcUtils.createMessage(MIME_TYPE, payload), detectedTag)) {

        //  Toast.makeText(this, "Wrote '" + tagWriteMessage + "' to a tag!", 
        //          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  setTagWriteReady(false);
    //  } else {
        //  Toast.makeText(this, "Write failed. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //  }
    }
}

public void processReadIntent(Intent intent) {
     Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "process read intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    List<NdefMessage> intentMessages = NfcUtils.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
    List<String> payloadStrings = new ArrayList<String>(intentMessages.size());

    for (NdefMessage message : intentMessages) {
        for (NdefRecord record : message.getRecords()) {
            byte[] payload = record.getPayload();
            String payloadString = new String(payload);

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(payloadString))
                payloadStrings.add(payloadString);
        }
    }

    if (!payloadStrings.isEmpty()) {
         content =  TextUtils.join(",", payloadStrings);
        //Toast.makeText(TagsActivity2.this, "Read from tag: " + content,
    //          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "a tag tem content", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //ver se existe con a internet
        if(conn.equals("yes")==true)
        {
            //Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "tem internet vai registar httpcon...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            httpcon2 task3 = new httpcon2();
            task3.execute(new String[] { "http://www.onetag.pt/metrodoporto/teste.php" });
            //estava a criar este erro por causa de ter o toast dentro do doinbackground
            //Android AsyncTask [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()]
        }
        else
        {
        //  Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "n tem internet vai guardar dados numa string...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);  
            tagsvisitadassemnet=gameSettings.getString("tagsvisitadas", "");
            tagsvisitadassemnet+=content+"%"+formattedDate+"%";
            //Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "dados guardados lidos sem net:"+tagsvisitadassemnet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = gameSettings.edit();
             prefEditor.putString("tagsvisitadas", tagsvisitadassemnet);

                prefEditor.commit();  
        }

    }
}


private class httpcon2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        SharedPreferences gameSettings = getSharedPreferences("MyGamePreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);  
         serverselecionado=gameSettings.getString("server", "");
         //Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, " httpcon2 servidor selecionado:"+serverselecionado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         if(serverselecionado.equals("metrodoporto")==true)
         {
            //Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "metro do porto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         urlpost="http://www.onetag.pt/metrodoporto_/saveBDregistos.php";
         }
         if(serverselecionado.equals("smartcom")==true)
         {
             //Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "smartcom", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         urlpost="http://www.onetag.pt/smartcom/saveBDregistos.php";
         }

        //String urlget="http://www.onetag.pt/metrodoporto/teste.php?user="+txtperson.getText().toString()+"&pass="+txtpass.getText().toString();
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrospost=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parametrospost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario",user));
        parametrospost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mimecode",content));

        Log.i("Inicio","vai entrar no try");
        String resposta = null;
        try{
            //Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "entrou no try com o  server"+urlpost, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            resposta= http.executHttpPost(urlpost, parametrospost);
            String resposta2=resposta.toString();
            resposta2=resposta.replaceAll("\\a+"," ");
            Log.i("Inicio","resposta:"+resposta2 );

        }
        catch(Exception erro)
        {
            Log.i("Inicio","Erro:"+erro );
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtoasterro,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.texttag);
            text.setText("Sucesso");

            Toast toast = new Toast(TagsActivity2.this);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();

        }
        return resposta;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(TagsActivity2.this, "Registo adicionado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Notas="";
        //Tarefas="";
        //TarefasNFeitas="";
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtoast,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.texttag);
        text.setText("Sucesso");

        Toast toast = new Toast(TagsActivity2.this);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
        //startActivityForResult(new Intent(TagsActivity2.this, TagsActivity2.class),2);*/
    }
  }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText( TagsActivity2.this, "tagsactivity2 onactivity result:"+resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(resultCode==2){
        setResult(2);
        finish();
    }
}

}
```

**Manisfest.xml:**
 
Here is the part that corresponds to this activity.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".TagsActivity2"
       android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            launchMode="singleTask"
      >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/com.smartcom.onetagv4.tag2" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/com.smartcom.onetagv4.tag2" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The code works, i just want to press the close button, and close all activity's.

Answer (score 2):

In case of an NFC intent a new task stack is created containing a new instance of your activity. This explains the behaviour that you observed: when you exit it, the other (earlier) instance is shown again. To prevent this, you can declare the activity in the manifest with `android:launchmode=singleTask` (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). This may have other side-effects in your app, though, because the activity can then only be at the root of an activity stack.

Comment: it is already declared as singletask as you can see in the manifest.xml...samething happens again.

Comment: ive change to singleinstance, the same happens,  exit button pressed, the current task is close, the earlier task appear, then exit button again closes everything...is there another way around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

ive resolve this by doing this :

```
startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

when starting an activity ,and when exit button is pressed i am doing this

```
setResult(2);
finish();
```

and in every activities i have got this , to handle the code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==2){
        setResult(2);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: this works for me on a NFC project!

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
//bla bla do what you want to do, like write a tag or read it 
finish();
}
}
```

have fun!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, and I don't know that I do... I think what your talking about is the backstack? There is a backstack - you probably want finishOnTaskLaunch or noHistory to be applied to the activity. I haven't read all your code.

I've found it quite difficult to understand exactly where the problem is... hope this helps